# Vb.net error for query and database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Dim datetimepicker1 As String = Format(System.DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

```
    Try
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_product (`prod_name`,`prod_desc`, `cat_id`, `uom_id`,`uom_num`, `dept_id`, `brand_id`, `size_id`, `type_id`, `remarks`, `date`) values (@prod_name,@prod_desc,@cat_id,@uom_id,@uom_num,@dept_id,@brand_id,@size_id,@type_id,@remarks,@date)"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_name", TextBox1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod_desc", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat_id", ComboBox1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uom_id", ComboBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uom_num", TextBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id", ComboBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand_id", ComboBox4.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@size_id", ComboBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_id", ComboBox6.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", RichTextBox1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", datetimepicker1)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()

        End With

            MsgBox(" SIze Successfully added")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)



        End Try
```

cannot add or update child row foreign key constraint fails this is my error

this is my table structure***********************8

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_brand`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_brand` (
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `brand_desc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`brand_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_brand`

INSERT INTO `tbl_brand` (`brand_id`, `brand_name`, `brand_desc`) VALUES
(1, 'Nike ', 'Nike Air '),
(2, 'Crocs ', 'Class A '),
(3, 'SafeGuard ', 'SafeGuard ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_category`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_category` (
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `cat_desc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_category`

INSERT INTO `tbl_category` (`cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_desc`) VALUES
(1, 'Bath Soap ', 'Bath Soap '),
(2, 'Detergent ', 'Detergent ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_dept`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_dept` (
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dept_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `dept_desc` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dept_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_dept`

INSERT INTO `tbl_dept` (`dept_id`, `dept_name`, `dept_desc`) VALUES
(1, 'Shoes ', 'Shoes '),
(2, 'Soap ', 'Soap ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_product`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_product` (
  `prod_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `prod_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `prod_desc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uom_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `remarks` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uom_num` int(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`prod_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_9` (`type_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_10` (`uom_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_11` (`size_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_12` (`dept_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_13` (`cat_id`),
  KEY `tbl_product_ibfk_14` (`brand_id`)
); ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_size`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_size` (
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `size_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`size_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_size`

INSERT INTO `tbl_size` (`size_id`, `size_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Small(S) '),
(2, 'Medium(M) '),
(3, 'Large(L) ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_type`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_type` (
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_type`

INSERT INTO `tbl_type` (`type_id`, `type_name`) VALUES
(1, 'BaskertBall Shoes '),
(2, 'Jersey Shorts '),
(3, 'running shoes '),
(8, 'Bath Soap ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_uom`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_uom` (
  `uom_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uom_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uom_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_uom`

INSERT INTO `tbl_uom` (`uom_id`, `uom_name`) VALUES
(1, 'kilogram(kg) '),
(2, 'Gram(g) '),
(3, 'Milligram(Mg) '),
(4, 'Liter(L) '),
(5, 'Milliliters(ml) '),
(6, 'Pieces(pcs) '),
(7, 'foot(ft) ');

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `tbl_user`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_code` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_level` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `com_code` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_code` (`user_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `tbl_user`

INSERT INTO `tbl_user` (`user_id`, `user_code`, `user_password`, `user_name`, `user_level`, `datetime`, `com_code`) VALUES
(1, '1024', '1024', 'Vincent Dematera', 3, '2012-01-10 18:18:33', '001'),
(7, '14 ', '14', 'Megan Bueno', 1, '2012-10-30 21:56:14', '002'),
(8, '13', '13', 'Anonymous', 1, '2012-10-20 21:51:00', '002'),
(9, '9', '9', 'boom', 1, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '003');

--

### -- Constraints for dumped tables

--

### -- Constraints for table `tbl_product`

ALTER TABLE `tbl_product`

ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_type` (`type_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`uom_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_uom` (`uom_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_size` (`size_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_dept` (`dept_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_category` (`cat_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_14` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_brand` (`brand_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_type` (`type_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`uom_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_uom` (`uom_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`size_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_size` (`size_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`dept_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_dept` (`dept_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_category` (`cat_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_product_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_brand` (`brand_id`);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: You'll need to show us your table structure, as a foreign key constraint failure implies you are inserting data that won't join up with another table.

Comment: is my code right ? if my code is right therefore im having problems with my backend

Comment: Foregin key constraint could mean either problem with code or problem with table design - can't be sure until we see your table design.

Answer (score 0):

You have a significant number of foreign key constraints for your table product.  For example, any "size_id" you enter into table products HAS to correspond to a "size_id" in table size.

What your vb.net program is telling you is that one of the id values you are entering into table product does not exist in its corresponding table.  My best guess would be that one of your id values (ie. `size_id`, `uom_id`, etc) is empty, blank, or zero.

You have a number of options - you can:

- turn foreign key off for the table if you wish with `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`
- you can remove the foreign keys altogether
- you can fix your code to ensure you are adhering to the foreign keys before you even attempt to insert a value

Comment: still Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails